# How to find the current URL in python mechanize?

Tags: python-2.7, mechanize-python

I see the answer to how to get the current URL in mechanize for Ruby ([mechanize how to get current url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032494/mechanize-how-to-get-current-url)) but how would one do so for the python mechanize?

The documentation doesn't seem very...thorough...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it may not be very thorough, but still [there is what you need](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/):

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://www.example.com/")
# follow second link with element text matching regular expression
response1 = br.follow_link(text_regex=r"cheese\s*shop", nr=1)

print response1.geturl()
```

As a side-note, when I'm looking for method like that and I don't find them in the docs, I usually open an IPython shell and I play with the autocompletion to see if there is some method that seems nice.

Comment: Thanks. And thanks for the advice as well. I'll be sure to do that too!:)